# Highlight an option in the ListView

Tags: c#

I created a ListView programmatically. I set the FullRowSelect option as true. After adding the elements to the ListView, if I start selecting the items, the row which is
currently selected is highlighted with a blue color. How can I disable the highlighting? I want to stop the highlighting of an item on its selection, but want FullRowSelect to be true.

Also, if I select an item, I want to change the color of the item so that anyone can easily identify which item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really control the display of items in a list is to use ownerdraw. This approach is not exposed in .NET, so will mean overriding the creation and WinProc of the list (at least).

Another option might be WPF, much of the styling of controls being overridable.